# How to write every x seconds a sound into an audio file (e.g. .mp3) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, while-loop

Is there a way to write for example every 2 seconds a sound in a (e.g. .mp3 or .wav) file in python?
For example if I have a loop like this

```
x=0
while x<10:
       #write sound.wav into an audio file (file.mp3)
       time.sleep(2)
       x=x+1
```

So as a result I want to have an audio file where you hear a sound every 2 seconds (and that for example 10 times)

Thanks in advance

Comment: teach yourself how to open up and read the payload from a wav file so you can iterate across each audio sample in the payload ... start with a mono audio file ... as this loop progresses byte by byte understand meaning of a multi byte audio sample where you need to stitch together say 2 bytes into a single audio sample when your input wav file has a bit depth of 16 bits ( 2 bytes ) ... plot these audio samples so you can see the curve as it wobbles up and down across the zero level ... force the hand by overwriting the sample values to zero ... in this loop write out samples to an output file

Comment: these are the necessary preliminary stills which will allow you to solve your question ... digital audio has two essential attributes:   bit depth and sample rate ... avoid any library to solve my above steps because if you write all that logic yourself you will learn much more than merely calling someone else's api which anyone can do ... if your input audio is mp3 first decode it into PCM format which is the format of wav which is the lingua franca of digital audio ... have fun

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped me a lot. I will try to teach myself the whole thing;-)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like that. If you `sleep(2)`, the Python interpreter will just idle for 2 seconds and not do anything, i.e. it will pause any file writes and resume after the sleep is over. What you need to do is to write your sound data, then write two seconds of silence (zero-valued samples), then write the sound data again etc.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. Can you maybe tell me how I can do something like that? To write several sounds in one file? I have unfortunately found nothing on the internet. Thanks

Comment: Well, in a sense you always write several sounds, because you almost always would write several samples into the file. Please try to search for "read and write audio files in Python". Then if you run into trouble, post another question.